# How do I merge two Home folders into one after reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: home-directory

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04.2. During installation, I picked another user-name for my profile.

I ended up with two Home folders, and after installation, I could not see my old files that used to be in my old Home Folder.

When I boot from a live CD, I can see 2 Home Folders inside `Volume`, and I can access them. How do I join or merge them into one?

Comment: thanks for helping, I figured it out on my own already with `sudo nautilus` I can move and link those files into my new default `Home Folder`.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what you did, but linking (?) doesn't sound like a solid solution, and it won't give you the right permissions. Why not just move the files you want to keep to either one?

Comment: yes Jacob Vlijm that exactly what I did because I wasn't exactly concerned about other Home Folder I just wanted data to be joined or moved to my current Home Folder. It's just the first time I completely reinstalled Ubuntu so I got confused after that. But thanks for responding. :)

Comment: Why don't one of you write this up as an answer that a more inexperienced user could follow so that they can benefit from your experience?

Comment: yep actually I could do this, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out both `Home Folders` could be found inside  `/home`. I copied all the files that I needed and/or wanted from my old profile to my new `Home Folder`. I simply copied & pasted.

At last I deleted my old profile that I didn't need anymore. To do that, you can use

```
sudo rm -r <directory>
```

or simply type `sudo rm -r`, and just drag & drop the folder over the terminal window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

That's it.

Comment: What if the old directory is in different partition?

Comment: well in my case I had it on the same partition but I don't think that could be an issue your current system is using the default Home directory that is active now your old Home directory just left aside.